# How do I move a theme from the node_modules folder to the project main directory in Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby, yarnpkg

I'm using this theme for a knowledge base and the theme files are contained within a node_modules/ folder with the rest of the stuff that doesn't need any changes. The theme folder structure is practically the same as a gatsby src and static folders.

I need the theme folder out of the node_modules and in the src and static folders. Will I face any linking issues if I did this manually?

Comment: What "linking" issues do you mean? Try it to see what happens. What do you need from the theme structure?

Comment: @FerranBuireu I am a bit more educated about this than I was 2 days ago. I want to make a few changes to some of the theme components. This means that I could shadow a component in the site source. But the theme file I want to shadow has imports from other theme files. Does it mean that I have to shadow those files just for the sake of importing them? I might as well shadow the whole theme folder?

Answer (score 0):

> This means that I could shadow a component in the site source. But the
> theme file I want to shadow has imports from other theme files. Does
> it mean that I have to shadow those files just for the sake of
> importing them? I might as well shadow the whole theme folder?

You should only shadow the components you want to override. Imagine it as if your component extends from the shadowed. Because of that, all the imports from the other theme components will be available in yours.

From the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/plugins-and-themes/shadowing/#customizing-the-bio-component):

> Any file that lives in the src/gatsby-theme-blog directory of the
> user’s site will be used instead of a file with the same name located
> in the theme’s src directory: `gatsby-theme-blog/src`. T**his replaces the
> entire file: to re-use parts of the original file from the theme such
> as functionality or styling, check out the sections of this doc on
> extending and importing shadowed files.**